# Which is the first book about a movie?

Tags: first-appearance

Movies are often based on books. But when was the first time when a book was published about a movie? Example : a [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sholay:_The_Making_of_a_Classic) was published about the Indian movie Sholay. Now this book is about the making of movie, but in my question the movies might not necessarily be so. But of course, movie should be an integral part of the book.

Comment: You mean about a movie or based on a movie?

Comment: I meant "about a movie" but If there is one based on a movie i.e. book adaptation of a movie, knowing that would be great.

Comment: *"I meant "about a movie"* - Really? This seems extremely fuzzy to define. Would it be sufficient if the book mentioned a movie on one page or does the movie have to be an integral (whatever that means) part of the story? Apart from that I can't seem to take any reasonable fascination from the first written record of a movie, but that may only be me.

Comment: No I am not asking about first written record of a movie. Of course not like if the book mentioned a movie on one page. The movie has to be an integral part of the story.

Comment: That poses the question of how you would define what an integral part of the story is. How important does the movie have to be for the story. (Sorry to bug you, but this question just remains very fuzzy to me.)

Comment: @Ankit it was probably written by Alan Dean Foster. Check this out... http://www.amazon.com/Alan-Dean-Foster/e/B000AQ39HU/ref=dp_byline_cont_pop_book_1

Comment: 2001: A Space Odyssey (novel) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2001:_A_Space_Odyssey_%28novel%29 (1968)

Comment: @BenPlont, I think that's a novelization of the film, which is somewhat different. What Ankit is asking for is a book that is in someway thematically 'about' a film.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Then I unofficially submit the first Star Wars novel (1976)...

Comment: @BenPlont, Nope. Also a novelization, [although based on a pre-existing screenplay,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_From_the_Adventures_of_Luke_Skywalker) and not a film. But you're still not registering the orientation of the question: how is 'Star Wars' thematically about 'a film'?

Comment: so like Cassavetes on Cassavetes (http://books.google.com/books/about/Cassavetes_on_Cassavetes.html?id=_1OELt31O70C) ...But for a specific movie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Katharine Hepburn](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000031/) wrote a biography about the making of [The African Queen](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0043265/). The book was titled: [The Making of the African Queen: Or How I Went to Africa With Bogart, Bacall and Huston and Almost Lost My Mind](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0394562720)

The movie came out in 1951. The book came out in 1987. I'm guessing someone will find an earlier book, but it's the first one I could think of.